# Server Side Facebook Authentication

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

Following this tutorial I am able to login to a Facebook account regardless of the account logged into the integrated iOS Facebook which is what I wanted :). However, now since Safari is remembering you logged in, if you go back to your page it shows you as being logged in.

I would like to make it so every time I click on the button that takes me to my php script to login, it forces me to login again. I know it might sound weird but I have a good reason behind why I need this.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't force someone to log out of facebook. Once the user is logged in and has authorized your application, it will post back to your application without showing any of the facebook login screens.

Comment: Does the application recognize that there is a logged in user based on the php in the server or based on the fact that they are logged in in Safari.

My end goal is to have multiple users in my app where each user can connect their profile in my app to their Facebook account and my app will remember the Facebook account that is associated with each user. So I am stuck at this point: User 1 logs in and connects, then the app is switched to User 2 and when User 2 goes to login it will think they are logged in with the first users Facebook account. :\

Comment: The session with facebook is stored in the browser. So facebook ends up using it automatically. The only way around this is having the user go to facebook and log out manually.